# XAML DesignData inside Custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Been looking into this question for long time and couldn't find an answer. Please let me explain it more.

If you start a new project, let say Windows 8.1 project, and you put a Button inside your MainPage.xaml you will see that the Button has a content of "Button" inside of it. This is text "Button" is pre-defined inside the style of the button. This is easy.

How about if you want to make a custom control that inherit from Control and it has a DependancyProperty called Days which is of type List inside it. How would you populate this property in DesignTime in a similar fashion as the Button?

Comment: .NET Collection controls are *not* populated at design time in Visual Studio until a valid `Binding Source` has been set.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for the info, didn't know about that. Been working on a custom Control just as described in the question. It drives me nut. It fails in design mode but not run mode. Do you mind get a look at it?